# After NPM update, global packages downloaded to different folder

Tags: npm

So I updated my npm. It then set my npm root to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules. All my old global packages are at /usr/local/lib/node_modules. Also, when I try to access a global, npm tries to access the old folder. As a result, I download packages to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules and access packages at /usr/local/lib/node_modules. How do I adjust npm root? I've tried to change NODE_PATH, didn't help. Driving me nuuuuts. THANKS in advance!

Comment: why not use `nvm` to handle your node versions and paths?

Comment: Had no idea something like that existed to be honest. Thanks for the heads up. Will look into it but I'd like to figure out how to fix the problem at hand. It looks like it just appended the new filepath to the old filepath. How do I change npm root. It doesn't seem like something I can set with npm config set.

Comment: `npm config get prefix` and `npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`

Comment: Didn't work, but I ended up going the nvm route and nuking my old npm node config and global packages.

Comment: `nvm` has been essential for me, every time we have build issues i switch and test several different npm versions

Comment: For some reason I didn't think the package manager had a manager and was able to resolve itself on updates. Though I do remember seeing nvm on Travis builds. Anywho, thanks a lot @Claudiordgz